# How to impl conversion between different inner types?

Tags: rust

This yields E0119:

```
#![feature(destructuring_assignment)]

pub struct Point<T> {
        pub x: T,
        pub y: T,
    }

impl<F, T: From<F>> From<Point<F>> for Point<T> {
    fn from<F>(f: Point<F>) -> Self {
        let Point { mut x, mut y } = f;
        (x, y) = (T::from(x), T::from(y));
        Self { x, y }
        }
    }
```

The implementation conflict is in std::convert::From for T:

```
impl<T> From<T> for T {
    fn from(t: T) -> T {
        t
    }
}
```

I assume there isn't a way to work around this so much as there may be more rust-idiomatic approach to the problem of converting between inner types, or even a more idiomatic understanding of what the "problem" is.

Comment: In this case, my recommendation would be not to provide a `From` trait but to simply impl a custom method called, say, `convert` on `Point`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it as a normal method that takes a closure and then pass it the `From::from` trait method when you call it. Or even specialize it for types that implement `From<T>`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Point<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
}

impl<T> Point<T> {
    pub fn map<U>(self, mut f: impl FnMut(T) -> U) -> Point<U> {
        let Point { x, y } = self;
        Point {
            x: f(x),
            y: f(y),
        }
    }

    pub fn map_into<U: From<T>>(self) -> Point<U> {
         let Point { x, y } = self;
         Point {
             x: U::from(x),
             y: U::from(y),
         }
     }
}

fn main() {
    let point_i16 = Point { x: 6i16, y: 3200i16 };
    let point_f32: Point<f32> = point_i16.map(From::from);
    let point_f64: Point<f64> = point_f32.map_into();
    println!("{:?}", point_f64); // Point { x: 6.0, y: 3200.0 }
}
```